# Meaning of 道々 and 口々

Tags: meaning, words, reduplication

I wanna clarrified meaning of these words. Is that right 道々 is  'along the way' and mean of  口々 is 'bad mouthing'? Is there any chance that both of them have another means?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "along the way" is rare and that of "every road" is far more dominant for 道々.

口々 doesn't mean "bad mouthing" but "every mouth". It almost only appears in this set phrase: （人々は、みな）口々に言う (Everyone says).